# Running this C# project - `Resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" cannot be found`

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I just downloaded this project and I get the following error

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ChromeSample, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2318,5): error MSB3552: Resource file "Properties\Resources.resx" cannot be found.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am using VS2012 - Windows 7 for building it. Any suggestions on how I could fix it. I havent used C# in a long time and need to see if this works immediately.

Comment: Check whether you have the file or not under properties folder?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In solution explorer, open tree item `Properties`.

Right click and Select `remove from project` for AssemblyInfo.cs, Resources.resx and  Settings.settings.

You can build.

Comment: On Visual Studio 2019, it becomes `exclude from project`

Answer (score 1):

Going through the posted MSDN URL, below are the list of files you have. So, you are getting that error cause you don't have a file named `Resources.resx` in there.

You can add one from visual studio though if needed be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 expand the My Project tree in the solution explorer and then select flies and under the tree and right and click Exclude from project.

Then clean and Rebuild.

Hope this.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 Windows 10

I added a resx file and for some reason it wasn't showing in the solution tree.
Trying to guess what happened, I removed the file from the folder. After that, the project wasn't building because the "resource file ... cannot be found" error.

What worked for me:

I opened the csproj file and deleted the entries related to that file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Source Control Explorer. Find your project, right click and select Add Items to Folder. Select Properties and in there should be your missinProperties\Resources.resx

Answer (score 0):

VB:

I was previously use VB2008 and when changed to 2015 I got the error "file not found:  progName.resX

I finally noticed that there were 3 modules that had a file named "NET Managed resourse (progName1).resourse" and the same for progName3, but the original name for the progName2 file was "Net Managed resourses (progName2(1)).resourses"

I just renamed the file and deleted the (1) and VB 2015 found it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer, open tree item Properties.

delete Resources.resx and rebuild project.

good luck!